# Problema con Encriptación y Desencriptacion en FingerPrint

Tags: android, android-studio

en la app que estoy desarrollando me piden que capture un valor y lo almacene en las SharedPreferences (rut), eso lo hago correctamente en login.java.

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 
MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
            editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("rut", login.getText().toString().replaceAll("[.-]", ""));
            editor.apply();
```

Deseo encriptar ese dato con keystore y luego desencriptar. Es ahi en donde tengo el problema, al momento de desencriptar me figura un error "Failed to encrypt the data with the generated key.Unsupported IV length: 16 bytes. Only 12 bytes long IV supported"

```
public class FingerPrintActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = FingerPrintActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private static final String DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG = "myFragment";
private static final String SECRET_MESSAGE = "Very secret message";
private static final String KEY_NAME_NOT_INVALIDATED = "key_not_invalidated";
String DEFAULT_KEY_NAME = "default_key_name";
final String PREFS_NAME ="my_name_preferences" ;
private  final String TRANSFORMATION = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";
SecretKey ENCRIPT_MESSAGE;
private byte[] iv ;

private KeyStore mKeyStore;
private KeyGenerator mKeyGenerator;
private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
private Context context;
private LocalStorage storage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("rut", null);

    if (restoredText != null) {
        String valorRut = prefs.getString("rut", null);
        DEFAULT_KEY_NAME = valorRut.toString();

    }
    configFinger();
}

public void configFinger()
{
    try {
        mKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get an instance of KeyStore", e);
    }
    try {
        mKeyGenerator = KeyGenerator
                .getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, "AndroidKeyStore");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get an instance of KeyGenerator", e);
    }
    Cipher defaultCipher;

    try {
        defaultCipher = Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
                + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get an instance of Cipher", e);
    }
    mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    KeyguardManager keyguardManager = getSystemService(KeyguardManager.class);
    FingerprintManager fingerprintManager = getSystemService(FingerprintManager.class);

    if (!keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()) {

        Toast.makeText(this,
                "La pantalla de bloqueo seguro no se ha configurado.\n"
                        + "Vaya a 'Configuración -> Seguridad -> Huella digital' \n" +
                        "para configurar una huella digital",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return;
    }

    if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {

        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Vaya a 'Configuración -> Seguridad -> Huella digital' y registre al menos un "+
                        " huella dactilar",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    createKey(DEFAULT_KEY_NAME, true);

    ValidaHuella(defaultCipher,DEFAULT_KEY_NAME);
}

private boolean initCipher(Cipher cipher, String keyName) {
    try {
        mKeyStore.load(null);
        SecretKey key = (SecretKey) mKeyStore.getKey(keyName,null);

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        iv = cipher.getIV();


        return true;
    } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
            | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
    }
}

public void onPurchased(boolean withFingerprint,
                        @Nullable FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject) {
    if (withFingerprint) {

        assert cryptoObject != null;
        tryEncrypt(cryptoObject.getCipher());
    } else {

        showConfirmation(null);
    }
}

private void showConfirmation(byte[] encrypted) {

    if (encrypted != null) {


        Toast.makeText(this, "Encript"+encrypted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

private void tryEncrypt(Cipher cipher) {
    try {

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(DEFAULT_KEY_NAME.getBytes());
        showConfirmation(encrypted);
        desenCript(DEFAULT_KEY_NAME);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to encrypt the data with the generated key. "
                + "Retry the purchase", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to encrypt the data with the generated key." + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void createKey(String keyName, boolean invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment) {

    try {
        mKeyStore.load(null);

        KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyName,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7).build();


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
           // builder.setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(invalidatedByBiometricEnrollment);
        }


        mKeyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec);
        mKeyGenerator.generateKey();


    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
            | CertificateException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}

public String desenCript(String keyName) throws KeyStoreException,
        CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        IOException, UnrecoverableEntryException,
        NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
        InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

    mKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    mKeyStore.load(null);
    final KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) mKeyStore
            .getEntry(keyName, null);

    final SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyEntry.getSecretKey();
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");

    final GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(128,iv);

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new GCMParameterSpec(128,iv));

    //byte[] decodedData = cipher.doFinal(DEFAULT_KEY_NAME.getBytes());
    byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(DEFAULT_KEY_NAME, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    final String unencryptedString = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
   // String encrypted = Base64.decode(unencryptedString, Base64.NO_WRAP);
   // Log.i(TAG, "desenCript: valor unencryptedString "+unencryptedString);

    //Toast.makeText(this,"Valor Desencript" new String(cipher.doFinal(bytes), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)));
        Log.i(TAG, "desenCript: Valor Desencript "+ new String(cipher.doFinal(bytes)));
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(bytes));
}


private void ValidaHuella (Cipher mCipher, String mKeyName){

    if (initCipher(mCipher, mKeyName)) {

        FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment fragment
                = new FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment();
        fragment.setCryptoObject(new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(mCipher));
        boolean useFingerprintPreference = mSharedPreferences
                .getBoolean(getString(R.string.use_fingerprint_to_authenticate_key),
                        true);
        if (useFingerprintPreference) {
            fragment.setStage(
                    FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment.Stage.FINGERPRINT);
        } else {
            fragment.setStage(
                    FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment.Stage.PASSWORD);
        }
        fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    } else {

        FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment fragment
                = new FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment();
        fragment.setCryptoObject(new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(mCipher));
        fragment.setStage(
                FingerprintAuthenticationDialogFragment.Stage.NEW_FINGERPRINT_ENROLLED);
        fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    }

}
```

}

El valor es recibido correctamente desde SharedPreferences, llevo varios días en esto y ya desconozco que puede suceder.